# No sound from any playback devices Ubuntu 14.04 fresh install

Tags: 14.04, sound, laptop, playback

I installed **Ubuntu 14.04** lts and now there is **no audio or sound from laptop's speakers or any headphone or anything else**.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed gstreamer plugin ? 
To install it launch software centre and install ubuntu restricted extras.